# How to make ALB slow_start work during ECS update service

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

For my high-traffic containerized app running in ECS Fargate, slow ramp-up is required for new containers, to avoid out of memory situation immediately after startup. This is especially important during the update service operation when all the containers are replaced at the same time.

How can I get this to work with ECS Fargate and ALB, making sure the old containers stay around until the `slow_start` period for the new containers is over?

This is my current terraform setup. I enabled `slow_start`, but during update service the old containers are stopped too early, so that the new containers get full traffic instantly.

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "my_target_group" {
  name        = "my_service"
  port        = 8080
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.active.id
  target_type = "ip"
  slow_start  = 120

  health_check {
    enabled             = true
    port                = 8080
    path                = "/healthCheck"
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    healthy_threshold   = 2
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_service" {
  name                               = "my_service"
  cluster                            = aws_ecs_cluster.my_services.id
  task_definition                    = aws_ecs_task_definition.my_services.arn
  launch_type                        = "FARGATE"
  desired_count                      = var.desired_count
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 400
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 100
  enable_execute_command             = true

  wait_for_steady_state = true

  network_configuration {
    subnets         = data.aws_subnets.private.ids
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_service_container.id]
  }

  load_balancer {
    container_name   = "my-service"
    container_port   = 8080
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.my_target_group.arn
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    ignore_changes        = [desired_count]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try with [stopTimeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#ContainerDefinition-stopTimeout).

Comment: Hmm, I think the stopTimeout is used only for containers that refuse to shutdown and need to be forcefully killed. This is not the case here, my application shuts down cleanly.

Comment: Have you tried setting a larger value in the `deregistration_delay` option?

Comment: The documentation says that the default deregistration_delay is 300 seconds, however my containers are stopped after ~40 seconds already, as soon as the new ones are up and running. Also my requests have a very low response time around 10-30ms, so I think that deregistration is not the main concern here. My feeling is that the ECS deployment does not know about the ALB slow_start feature, so it terminates the containers before the ramp up is finished.

Comment: What is your desired_count? I wonder if the issue is the min% is too low, resulting in ECS deployment terminating 'old' tasks too early - this leaves only 'new' tasks so they are immediately dropped out of slow-start mode?

Comment: Desired count is normally 4, but I always need to update it manually to 8 before deploying new releases, because otherwise I run into out of memory issues. A few minutes after deployment is finished I scale it down to 4 again. Min% is set to 100

Answer (score 0):

`aws ecs` usually sends `sigterm` to gracefully shutdown and sends `sigkill` if 30 second passed.

So, you can handle this `sigterm` signal (example to catch this signal in [python](https://gist.github.com/fortejas/92dd1144333c471bea53b5532b554635)) and add delay in your code. After that, you need to adjust `sigkill` 30 second wait with `stopTimeout` in `ContainerDefinition` to stop `aws` shutting down the `ecs`.

Comment: Maybe this is worth a try, but sounds more like a workaround than a real solution. I'll try it out and see if it helps